# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, search

hope someone of you can help me.
On my wordpress-page, i get the following messages, when I use the search function and there are no results:

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/tronicmart.de/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/oceanwp/inc/helpers.php on line 3392

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/tronicmart.de/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/oceanwp/inc/helpers.php on line 3400

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/tronicmart.de/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/oceanwp/inc/helpers.php on line 3406

```php
    if ( ! function_exists( 'oceanwp_excerpt' ) ) {

    function oceanwp_excerpt( $length = 30 ) {
        global $post;

        // Check for custom excerpt -->line 3392
        if ( has_excerpt( $post->ID ) ) {
            $output = $post->post_excerpt;
        }

        // No custom excerpt
        else {

            // Check for more tag and return content if it exists -->line 3400
            if ( strpos( $post->post_content, '<!--more-->' ) ) {
                $output = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
            }

            // No more tag defined -->line 3406
            else {
                $output = wp_trim_words( strip_shortcodes( $post->post_content ), $length );
            }

        }

        return $output;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are no search results, then it is somewhat expected that the `$post` variable is empty and there are no properties in it to be used in the if statements.

You can prevent the error by adding an if statement to make sure `$post` is what it is supposed to be before the line 3392.

`if ( ! is_object($post) || ! is_a($post, 'WP_Post') ) ) { 
return; 
}`

Or the lazy way
`if ( empty( $post->ID ) ) { 
return; 
}`

You can always use `var_dump` to check / debug your variables to make sure they contain the stuff you need.

Comment: On the other hand, if there is no post, then no excerpt should be printed? So your fix is only a cover up for a larger error...

Comment: I tried both of your code snippets and the second one works fine for me. Thank a lot!

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż, I understood that the error arises when there are no search results. In that situation there would be no $post object and trying to use its properties in the if statements would cause the errors as $post is null, right? Of course, in the case when there should be a $post and there isn't one, then the proposed fix will just mask the underlying problem.

Comment: @TronicM, you're welcome. If you want, you can mark my answer asvaccepted to let others know that your question has been solved.